# Generate random number only one time

Tags: java, android

I have a method who randomize a number between 1 and 5.
This method needs to stop when all 5 numbers are sorted too (isn't doing it now)

My actual code is:
`public ArrayList<String> generated = new ArrayList<String>();` on top

And the method itself is:

```
public int RandomizeQuestion () {
    // Question numbers
    final int min = 1;
    final int max = 5;

    Random r = new Random();
    int qran = r.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

    if (Collections.singletonList(generated).contains(qran)) {
        RandomizeQuestion();
    } else {
        generated.add(String.valueOf(qran));
    }

    return qran;
}
```

But that happens is all time the random number appears as new and this number is added repeatedly in generator array.

Comment: What do you think `Collections.singletonList(generated)` does?

Comment: Why does your method return a value?

Comment: Why aren't you checking the length of the list before recursing?

Comment: `Collections...` is a code left from another try. Already removed.    
My method returns because i call it in another method. I don't know if it's a better way to do this.

    `public void PopulateQ() {
        int qrandom = RandomizeQuestion();
    ...
    }`

Comment: If you're not using the return value, it should be `void`.

Comment: I'm using to set another variable in another method.

Comment: If you need the return value, you have to grab it from the recursive call as well: `qran = RandomizeQuestion();`. Note that recursion is altogether overkill here. A simple loop will suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collections.singletonList(generated)` returns a `List<ArrayList<String>>` containing `generated` as its only element. Obviously that won't contain `qran`. Also, you're not checking if the list is the expected length before attempting to add a new item. Something like this should work:

```
if (generated.size() < max - min + 1) {
    if (generated.contains(String.valueOf(qran))) {
        RandomizeQuestion();
    } else {
        generated.add(String.valueOf(qran));
    }
}
```

But here's a much simpler and more efficient way to shuffle a sequence of values:

```
// generate a list of values between min and max
generated = IntStream.rangeClosed(min, max)
        .map(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

// shuffle them
Collections.shuffle(generated);
```

Comment: I need to method to generate one number at time, but check if the number is already generated. If `yes`, generate a new number, if `no`return it.    

I'm calling this method in another, to generate this random number everytime.